# Too many SOQL queries: 101 in a Flow

Tags: soql, visual-workflow

a question regarding this error. I recently encountered this issue when testing out a record triggered flow that I deployed in one of my organization's environment (SIT) however, I tried replicating this issue on 2 lower environments (ST and DEV) but I wasn't able to encounter this issue and everything is working fine. Currently looking for answers on how best to resolve this. Thanks

A quick comparison on both flows from different environments

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please [edit] the question to show the exact failure, with logging, and to cover the specific flow detail. The illustration is also confusing since I cannot tell if you are trying to show the failure or just successful executions (I think the latter).